# How to log out from my account

Tags: support

How can I log out from my account when I am using a public computer, because closing the window does not log out?

Comment: This is a duplicate, by the way. I answered without searching first, ops...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on `StackExchange` at the top left, and then on `log out`

[image]